# Android app displays a high "User-perceived crash rate" in Play Console, but not many actual crashes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, google-play-console

I've got a gamified app for iOS and Android that we've developed in Unity, engine version 2020.3.27f1. After an update a few weeks ago, we saw our our numbers for the Android version's "User-perceived crash rate" start skyrocketing in the Google Play Console. Strangely, our numbers for actual reported crashes don't seem to have been affected at all.

The most likely culprit would be the upgraded Unity IAP package. In the first update (red circle on the graphs below), we upgraded from package version 4.5.0 to 4.5.1. In a later update (blue circle) we upgraded to 4.5.2 hoping it would alleviate the issue. In fact it seems to have made it worse.

[User-perceived crash rate graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jr0r.png)

[Actual crashes graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pU4J.png)

We have received no reports at all through any of our review or support channels that users are having issues with frequent crashing. We have a system for reporting users' error logs to us automatically when something goes wrong on their app, and the logs show nothing that suggests a new or very frequent issue. (Though it's always possible for the app to crash before being able to send off the log data.) Based on all available evidence, this seems to be an error on the Play Console's part.

Anyway, the obvious next step is to roll back the Unity IAP package version to 4.5.0. Thankfully we should be able to do that easily enough.

But I'm asking this question because I am at a loss for why this might happen like this, and what I could even do to start diagnosing this issue. Any thoughts or advice are appreciated.